# javascript fire and forget when link is clicked - async ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

We are storing events in our db. An event could be a page hit and save/update etc. From inside the controller action this is happening beautifully.

I have 3 links, when these are clicked, i want to store an event for this in the db. Rather than taking a user to a generic action to store the event and then doing response.redirect, i want to do this via jquery/ajax behind the scenes. Now when the user clicks the link, two things should happen

1. ajax request will create an event
2. user taken to the intended page.

I just want the user to click the link and the user gets to the intended page. **Behind the scenes processing shouldn't hold the user for another second or two on the page, while the code is waiting for a response from the remote action**. Do i need to wait for the ajax request to complete or just put "return true" in my jquery action? Since the user will be taken to the next page, will my ajax request go bad or stop? In firebug i have seen the ajax process to abort when the user clicks some link on the page before the ajax request has completed. How best can i do something like this?

Sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("a[custom-event]").on('click', function () {
                var label = $(this).attr("custom-event");
                var value = $(this).attr("custom-event-value"); 

        DoSomeAjaxProcessing('event', 'click', label, value); //don't want this to go bad if redirection happens immediately

                return true; //return true so that the browser can send the user to the href location
            });
        });
```

**Update 1:**

Will something like this fly for me. I am going to test and update as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("a[custom-event]").on('click', function () {
                    var label = $(this).attr("custom-event");
                    var value = $(this).attr("custom-event-value"); 

            (new Image).src = someurl+"?label="+label+"&value="+value+"&type=event&action=click";

                    return true; //return true so that the browser can send the user to the href location
                });
            });
```

Comment: You need to cancel the click and than follow the action when the callback is done.

Comment: hmmm this is what i am trying to avoid, i don't want to cancel the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to incur some cost if you're trying to record an event using your server. You cannot asynchronously make a call to your server to log the event and also serve the destination for that link simultaneously.

As you propose, the two paths you propose are unsatisfactory:

1. Make the AJAX call to your event logging route synchronous and only take the user to the destination after the logging is done. This incurs a delay on taking the user to their destination.
2. Provide a generic route that redirects the user to the correct route and records the proper event. This could break url schemes and funnels a lot of your traffic through a single route.

Here at Stack, we also use "events" to track user actions, but we can largely do so at the controller level at the *destination*.

For example, if you have a checkout flow that takes a user from a `/home` route to a `/login` route, we would track that event at the beginning of the controller that serves the `/login` view.

```
[Route("/login")]
public virtual ActionResult Login()
{
    // Tracking code here, probably passing in the referrer
    return View();
}
```

Comment: How does google analytics handle click tracking? Here click tracking and destination are served at the same time. All we do is onclick setup `ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', label, value)`.

Comment: I have gone with #2 here.